# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Tags: angular

Lets say i have two component parent and child and I'm trying to access the DOM element of Child component from parent component. But i'm facing issue of undefined native element.

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{
   @ViewChild('pdfData', { read: ElementRef }) domData: ElementRef;
   constructor()
   ngOnInit(): void {
    some code..
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.domData.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

Child component DOM element

```
<div #pdfData class="pdfData">
    <table *ngFor="let hubxReport of hubxReportList; let i=index">
      <tr>
        <th>{{hubxReport.categoryName}} + "Test"</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>{{column}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of hubxReport.hubxDataItems">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{item.itemTitle}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemValue}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemUnit}}</td>
        <td>{{item.normalRange}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And below code is Parent component and I'm trying to access Child component DOM element and the issue comes here.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{
@ViewChild('pdfData',{ read: ElementRef }) pdf: ChildComponent ;
constructor()
ngOnit(): void{
some code...
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.pdf.domData.nativeElement;
    console.log(this.pdf.domData.nativeElement) //undefine here
  }
downloadPDF(isSubmit:any) {  
    debugger      
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let rows: Array<any> = [];
    let header: Array<any> = [];
    let medicineInfo: any;
    let physicianInfo: any;
    //this.isShow = true;
    //this.changeRef.detectChanges();
    let content= this.pdf.domData.nativeElement; //undefine here
    let _elementHandlers =  
    {  
      '#editor':function(element,renderer){  
        return true;  
      }  
    };  
    doc.html(content.innerHTML,{  
            callback: function (doc) {
              doc.save();
            },
            x: 10,
            y: 80,
            // 'x': 15,
            // 'y': 15,
            width:190,  
            'elementHandlers':_elementHandlers  
          }); 
}
```

And here is my Stackblitz [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jzatra?file=src%2Fapp%2FchildComponent%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Try to reproduce it on StackBlitz. The code, as it is presented in the question, should work.

Comment: here is my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jzatra?file=src%2Fapp%2FchildComponent%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The StackBlitz has a completely different error due to this: `@ViewChild('pdfData', { read: ElementRef }) pdf: ChildComponent;` and even the fact that there's no child component rendered

Comment: how can i fix it, code is same i think issue is interrelated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you "pdfData" template reference variable belongs to "child", so you can not access using viewChild from "parent"

You can in parent

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <!--in click button you pass a template reference variable of the child-->
  <button ...  (click)="downloadPDF(child,false)" >
    Print
  </button>
  <!--see that you use a template reference variable in child-->
  <my-child #child></my-child>
</div>
```

Your function downloadPDF

```
downloadPDF(child:any,isSubmit: any) {
    ....
    let content = child.domData.nativeElement; //see how access to the property
                                               //domData of the "child"
                      //yes, by defect all the variables in Angular are public
                      //include the variables that makes reference
                      //to viewChild
    ...
}
```

See your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e3dmpi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: You should use "const" (not let) when declare a variable that has no change, e.g., better `const content=..` than `let content=...`

Comment: i only need to print the DOM element in pdf page but i have to hide it from my parent DOM.Currently DOM element is printing in both.How can i hide it from my parent DOM

Comment: any alternative way to print the DOM element only in pdf page

Comment: @ManipuriVlogs, you can enclose between a `<div style="display:none"><child #child></child></div>` (Sorry I don't know very well the library `jspdf` to know another "easy" way)

Comment: can you update it in the stackblitz. I only need to take the DOM data but i need to hide the DOM data from parentComponent. I tried <div style="display:none"><child #child></child></div> but its still printing

Answer (score 0):

In your stackblitz you are not using `my-child` element at all.

You can try accessing `pdfData` in child and then that variable in the parent.

So, `domData` is a variable declared in the child that reads from `pdfData` so it only exists and is accessible from the child. Since `pdfData` does not exist on your parent, reading it with `ViewChild` from here will return `undefined`, so you have to declare `domData` in the child.

You can, however, access the html variable in the child with `ViewChild` and assing it to a component variable (just like you are trying to do on the parent).

Then, on the parent you could `<my-child #myChild></my-child>` and

`ViewChild('myChild', read: ChildComponent) myChildComponent`.

This should give you access to all child properties, including the `pdfData` that comes from the child's `ViewChild` in the child (words are confusing)

`myChildComponent.pdfData.nativeElement` on `AfterViewInit`

[The forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uckqck?file=src%2Fapp%2FchildComponent%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: your stackblitz doesnt work