# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') in angular 14

Tags: angular-material, angular14

I am newly building in angular and stuck on the below issue.

I have a route let's say /claim on which I am trying to load a Mat-Tab but getting the below error.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

App.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    TransactionsComponent,
    ClaimDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AgGridModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthguardService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app routing module is

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { text: 'login' } },
  { path: 'transactions', component: TransactionsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] , data: { text: 'transactions' } },
  { path: 'claim', component: ClaimDetailsComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard],  data: { text: 'claim' } }


];
```

And my App component HTML is

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div style="    display: flex; justify-content: right;">
    <!-- style="width: 15%;position: relative;" -->
    <div *ngIf="auth.is logged in()" class="side nav menu-split" >
        <a [routerLink]="'/transactions'">Transactions</a>
        <a [routerLink]="'/login'">logout</a>
        <a [routerLink]="'/claim'">Claim</a>

    </div>
    <div class="main-content content-split">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my claims component just has a simple Mat Tab HTML but it gives me the error and does not load it properly

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Error screenshot

[image: This is the screenshot of the error]

May I know what I am doing it working and why my Mat-Tab component is not loading?

If I change to simple HTML like
`<p>Claims data</p>` then on /claims the data loads. But only for the Mat-Tab component, I am getting the error.

I am using Angular 14 for the development.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121154/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-nativeelement)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the reply but the answer you mentioned on this link ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121154/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-nativeelement ) doesn't solve my issue. Also, I have attached the error screenshot in my answers for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question too when using Angular v.14 to install Angular Material. Angular v.14 will auto install `"@angular/material": "^7.0.0"`.

If I change it to `"@angular/material": "^14.0.0"` in package.json, and do the `npm install` again, then everything is fine.

Upgrading to Angular v.15 also worked for me.